# Should I use WPF converter or trigger?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, triggers, converters

I was wondering how do you decide when to use `converters` and when to use `triggers`. I prefer using triggers for operations on GUI (like showing/hiding controls, changing their appearance etc.).

Some time ago I used a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` for this purpose but now, I just don't need it, I do all things connected to the `visibility` using a triggers and I even started to think "*what was the purpose of creating a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` by the MS team?".* Generally, when it's possible I try to use a declarative way to write the code - in this example - XAML.

What is your opinion of that?

Comment: trigger are used for single value check where converter used for complex and diffrent type of value conversion.

Comment: Similar question hinting towards performance cost of converters - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508159/datatrigger-vs-databinding-with-converter-performance-wise

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I agree with you, I also try to use declarative code in XAML and prefer `Triggers` instead of `Converters`.

In most of the scenarios triggers can perform the same work as any converter but `Converters` can have custom/business logic as pchajer mentioned.

One limitation of `Triggers` is that *Setters in your `DataTriggers` can only change properties of your UI elements*; so, **you can't update your ViewModels property with triggers**, thats where `Converters` win, remember the `ConvertBack` method.

So, **you can bind your VM property with a controls `Visibility` using `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` and even if your controls `visibility` is changed by some other means your VM property will get updated**; 
generally it's not required that's why `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` gets replaced by triggers.

So in short -

> *`Triggers` can only perform `OneWay` operations whereas `Converters` can perform `TwoWay` operations*

Comment: it's *funny* how this answer is almost exactly the same as [this other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19474466/540776)

Comment: @superjos I would say 'how other answer is almost exactly same as this one' :D Thanks for pointing that out, made me smile :)

Comment: yes, to stay on the subject, I just copy-pasted my comment here and there :)

Comment: It's appeared again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607952/wpf-xaml-datatriggers-or-valueconverters-best-practice.  This answer gets around.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you are looking from bottom-up and you just need to look top-down.

**Triggers**-When a specified condition is fulfilled it "triggers" an execution

**Converters**-Convert between two incompatible types.

Why do we need a boolean datatype when we can do the same functionality with intergers?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the functionality either by trigger or converter but from my option below possibility can be considered while taking decision

1. If you are using TDD approach for development then go for converters as you can write test cases.
2. If there is any business logic better to right code in converter and sometiems which can not be achieved through trigger.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said above I can only add:

- Triggers sometimes require to duplicate things, e.g. when you have more than one property for triggers you need to specify each an every combination
- Sometimes you will need code to properly convert from type A to B, then you have to use converters. Triggers are good if the value/property is already exposed from the VM in way, that you can use it for triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You should always do business related operations in the DomainModel objects, or at least in a ViewModel object.
Making some business work in converter is not a good option because Converters are designed to convert a value from one type to another.

Comment: Dida you see my question? I explicitly wrote: "for operations onGUI (like showing/hiding controls, changing their appearance etc.)". I know that business related options must be controlled on the DomainModel object.