# WPF XAML - DataTriggers or ValueConverters? Best practice

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger, valueconverter

I have a Window with a `TextBlock`. This `TextBlock` has to show the value "R" if the binded value is 0 or "M" if the binded value is 1.

I have two possibilities:

**ValueConverter approach**

```
<TextBlock Binding="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource valConverter}}"/>
```

Where `valConverter` is an `IValueConverter` class that returns "M" or "R" if the value is respectively 0 or 1.

```
[omitted class]
```

**DataTrigger approach**

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="R"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="M"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

According to you, what is the best approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF triggers VS Converter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466354/wpf-triggers-vs-converter)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use WPF converter or trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152313/should-i-use-wpf-converter-or-trigger/11156189#11156189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converters are Best in this scenario. As the name indicates converter converts the type. In this case you want to convert int to Char, so converters are much suitable.    For More Info : [ConverterPerformance](http://druss.pp.ua/2013/10/compare-performace-of-wpf-converters-and-datatriggers/)

Answer (score 4):

In most of the scenarios triggers can perform the same work as any converter but `Converters` can have custom/business logic.

One limitation of `Triggers` is that Setters in your `DataTriggers` can only change properties of your UI elements; so, you can't update your `ViewModels` property with triggers, that's where `Converters` win, remember the `ConvertBack` method.

So in short `Triggers` can only perform `OneWay` operations whereas `Converters` can perform `TwoWay` operations

Comment: If you copy an answer from earlier question then pls. provide a link to original question, will be more helpful for everyone.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11156189/45382